# Communication between two pthreads to display

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I have looked at other questions and still cant seem to understand this concept. I have created four threads and each thread needs to communicate with the same thread. (Min and Display), (Max and Display), and so on..
I know I need to use:

```
pthread_mutex_t myLock1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_lock(&myLock1);
(some global variable) = ....;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&myLock1);
```

Here is one of the threads I have created:

```
pthread_create(&minThread, NULL, (void *) mini, (void *) numbers);
pthread_join(minThread, (void *) &min);


void *mini(void *numbs1)
{
    int *numbers = (int *) numbs1;
    min = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *min = (numbers[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)    //Computing min value
    {
        if ( numbers[i] < *min )
        {
            *min = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Min has been computed.\n");

    pthread_exit(min);

}
```

I am now supposed to incorporate the use of another thread (disThread) to display the variable I have computed in minThread (min) and other similar threads that have done computations using those mutex system calls I have specified. How can I set this up correctly? Any tips are appreciated to further my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that using the mutex system calls are pretty simple. For anyone else who runs into a similar problem, the thread functions void *mini and void *disi follow this format:

```
void *mini(void *numbs1)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&theLock);
    int *numbers = (int *) numbs1;
    min = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *min = (numbers[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)    //Computing min value
    {
        if ( numbers[i] < *min )
        {
            *min = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&theLock);
    printf("Min has been computed.\n");

    pthread_exit(min);


}


void *disi()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&theLock);
    x = *min;                           //Displaying min value (x initialized as global variable)
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&theLock); 
    printf("The Minimum value is %d\n", x);
}
```

A mutex lock and mutex unlock should cover the range of a shared variable between two threads. This is so there is no interference between the two threads working simultaneously.